# Trigger mouse click on overlapping movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I have two MovieClips (same parent) that overlap, both have a listener for mouse click.

But only the top most MC detects the click.

Is it possible to get both MCs detect the click using listeners ?

If not, is collisions a better way to do it, than using the `getObjectsUnderPoint()` ?

Comment: is there a special requirement to have both overlaping?

Comment: of course! But I dont want to discuss that, although saying that its a game would bring some light to it :)

Comment: I asked as you could:) avoid overlaps, split clickable movieclips into 3 parts 2 separate and 1 overlapping. You can also useGetObjectsUnderPoint to delegate click.

Comment: More than just solve this issue, I want to now the general answer, is it possible to broadcast the click event on overlaping MCs ? getObjectsUnderPoint() has problems with coordinates

Comment: there is no direct way to do this other than workarounds

Comment: +1 for the direct and simple answer... I already know the workarounds! going for the colisions

Answer (score 0):

You can register the click event to a parent controller or class.  When it receives the event callback it can then broadcast that back to all the other child MCs from that callback function.  It's just a matter of managing the MCs - either keep a track of their names or add then all to an array so you can use a for loop to iterate through them.

Comment: No can do... there are other siblings MCs that dont get clicked and should not be triggered.

Comment: Then just register the ones that are important